# Sort an ArrayList<MyInterface>

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist, interface, compiler-errors

For rendering order purposes, I'm trying to sort an `ArrayList<MyInterface>` by the sum of two integers in each object. The objects in this `ArrayList` implement the same interface but doesn't have a motherclass in common.

```
class A implements MyInterface, Comparable<MyInterface> {

    @Override
    public int compareTo(MyInterface object1) {
        return (this.x+this.y)-(object1.getX()+object1.getY()); // Sort in ascending order
    }

    @Override
    public int getX() { return this.x; }

    @Override
    public int getY() { return this.y; }
    }

}

class B implements MyInterface, Comparable<MyInterface> {
    //Same than A, but A & B have no common motherclass.
}


interface MyInterface {

    int getX();
    int getY();
    int compareTo(MyInterface mi);

    ... //Other method that are the first reason I created the interface before.

}
```

Then I try to sort my arraylist like this:

```
ArrayList<MyInterface> myArrayList = new ArrayList<MyInterface>();
myArrayList.add(new A(1,2));
myArrayList.add(new A(5,6));
myArrayList.add(new B(3,1));
Collections.sort(gameRenderables); //I get the compile error here.
```

I get the error:

```
Bound mismatch: The generic method sort(List<T>) of type Collections is not applicable for the arguments (ArrayList<Renderable>). The inferred type Renderable is not a valid substitute for the bounded parameter <T extends Comparable<? super T>>.
```

Maybe I'm trying to make something impossible. If that is the case can you give me alternative solutions to this sorting problem?

Comment: `MyInterface` does not implement/extend `Comparable<...>`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've defined the class as implementing `Comparable` instead of defining the interface as extending `Comparable`. Without doing that, the Java compiler cannot know that every conceivable implementation of `MyInterface` is in fact `Comparable`. The fact that the interface has a `compareTo(MyInterface)` method that would match the method of a class implementing `Comparable<MyInterface>` is inconsequential.

To make a long story short:

```
interface MyInterface extends Comparable<MyInterface> {
    int getX();
    int getY();

    // No need for a compareTo method - we get it from the Comparable interface
}

class A implements MyInterface {
    // No changes required to your implementation
}
```

Comment: The only downside here is that the two implementations of `compareTo` have to be identical (or at least compatible with each other in terms of transitivity, etc.)

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth Good point! You could always use Java 8's default methods and implement `compareTo` in `MyInterface`, but I wasn't sure if I wanted to go there with my answer.

Comment: Thank you, all is working now! The project in using Java 7 so I can't use the "implement in the interface" solution. Still really handy!